# Generalized range / count functions for any type with __add__

Tags: python, iterator, abstraction, date-range

Basically, I would like to be able to simply do something like:

```
 from datetime import datetime, timedelta
 from itertools import count
 start, end = datetime(2017,1,1), datetime(2018,1,1)
 calendar = count(start, timedelta(days=1))
 # Or better
 calendar = range(start, end, timedelta(days=1))
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this using builting/stdlib functionality?
It says it needs a number on input - I think it should easily abstract  to anything you can use the `+` operator on, but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could of course redefine `count` to accept any types that can be added. Otherwise if you don't want to define your own types you can use `itertools` to do the same:

```
 calendar = itertools.accumulate( 
              itertools.chain( [start],
                               itertools.repeat( timedelta(days=1) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably can define your own `count` and `range` like:

```
def count(start, delta):
    cur = start
    while True:
        yield cur
        cur = cur + delta

def range(start, stop, delta):
    # probably need some assert start < stop
    cur = start
    while cur < stop:
        yield cur
        cur = cur + delta
```

Comment: Well of course, but it is not exactly what I was looking for.